# how to enable UITextField userinteraction property inside UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have `UITableViewCell` and inside that I have `UITextfield`, I  made 7 sections (dynamic) and each section have one cell (one row) which includes `UITextField` .

Now I have one button on right top corner of `UINavigationBar` (EDIT button).
I need to enable user interaction enable for all section textfields . Hows  that possible?

This is my `UITableviewCode`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    sharedManager=[Mymanager sharedManager];
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;
    NSString *text;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[timeLineDetailsCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
        [label setTag:1];

        [[label layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }

    if(indexPath.section==0){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:0];
    }else if(indexPath.section==1){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:1];
    }else if(indexPath.section==2){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:2];
    }else if(indexPath.section==3){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:3];
    }else if(indexPath.section==4){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:4];
    }else if(indexPath.section==5){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:5];
    }else if(indexPath.section==6){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:6];
    }else if(indexPath.section==7){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:7];
    }

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [cell.ds1 setText:text];
    [cell.ds1 setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    return cell;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text ;
    if(indexPath.section==0){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:0];
    }else if(indexPath.section==1){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:1];
    }else if(indexPath.section==2){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:2];
    }else if(indexPath.section==3){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:3];
    }else if(indexPath.section==4){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:4];
    }else if(indexPath.section==5){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:5];
    }else if(indexPath.section==6){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:6];
    }else if(indexPath.section==7){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:7];
    }


    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *str= [title objectAtIndex:section];
    return str;
}
```

my edit button code is

```
-(void)editTimeline{
    cell.ds1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cell.ds1 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    cell.ds1.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.ds1.layer.borderWidth=1;
  //  [cell.ds1 becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

when i click on EDIT button  only some rows are able to edit .please help me .

Comment: actually `cell.ds1` is updating every time a new cell is created or reused. that's why only some rows are able to edit. `cell.ds1` is the object which was added on last cell (new  or reused cell ) .

Comment: `if(indexPath.section==0){
        text = [contents objectAtIndex:0];` - What if you have 100 elemnents instead of 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define flag data memeber with Bool type

-(void)editTimeline{
    flag=true;
     [self.tableView reload];
}


add following condition in cellForRowAtIndexpath method


if(flag==true){
 [cell.ds1 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
}
else{
 [cell.ds1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

let me know if it help u....!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code -

```
    NSArray *cellArray=[itemsTable visibleCells];
    for (UITableViewCell *aCell in cellArray)
    {
        UITextField *myTField=(UITextField*)yourtextField;
        myTField.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }
```

`myTField` is added on cell as a subView with specific tag. You can get the `myTField` via `[aCell viewWithTag:someTag];`.

Answer (score 0):

Call cellForRowAtIndexPath for each row in your section, make it unselectable by the tableView (otherwise it will triger the tap instead of you) and enable user interactions in the way you want for you returned cell :3